# While loop + sleep slows down PC

Tags: java

I am currently writing a java programm that fetches the source code from a html and parses it for a value. This works fine normally, but once I try to let it run in a while loop and refetch the data every 30 seconds my PC slows down until I stop the program manually.

```
while(true) {                           
    try { 
                                URL url = new URL("https://www.reddit.com/r/gaming/");
                                URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();

                                System.out.println(urlConn.getContentType());  //it returns text/html

                                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
                                (new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));

                                File test = new File("test");
                                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(test));

                                String text;

                                while ((text = in.readLine()) != null) {

                                    writer.write (text);
                                }

                                writer.close();
                                in.close();

                                String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("test")), "UTF-8");

                                Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("title=(.*?)\">");
                                Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
                                if (matcher.find()) {
                                    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
                                    if (Integer.valueOf((matcher.group(1))) <= 99999999) {
                                        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                                        AudioInputStream inputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("alert.wav"));
                                        clip.open(inputStream);
                                        clip.start(); 
                                    }
                                }
        Thread.sleep(30000);

    } catch (MalformedURLException f) {
        f.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException f) {
        f.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException f) {
        f.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any hints on why this is happening?

Comment: Where is the code fetching the data?

Comment: Depending on how you manage your objects in the loop you may get memory leaks and high memory consumption. Without the complete code there is nothing we can do.

Comment: `UnsupportedAudioFileException` are you opening or doing something else with (large) audio files without properly closing them or otherwise freeing resources? I see now when you have added code that you open a stream but doesn't close it.

Comment: Added, just didn't want to bloat the code. This is currently just for testing puposes using the gaming reddit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the code, but I think that `Thread.sleep()` will only run if you don't throw.  I think you want to put it outside of the try/catch so that if you fail, you wait 30 seconds before trying again.  Otherwise, if something causes a `throw`, you will just retry again immediately and since nothing will have really changed since the last time you tried, you will immediately `throw` again over and over.

Right now, your code is:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        // Do a lot of things that can throw
        if(something_bad_happens) throw new Error();

        /*
         * This sleep will only be reached
         * if we don't throw
         */
        Thread.sleep(30000);
    } catch (errors) {
        // Deal with errors
    }
}
```

I think you actually want this:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        // Do a lot of things that can throw
        if(something_bad_happens) throw new Error();
    } catch (errors) {
        // Deal with errors
    }

    // Always sleep between attempts no matter what
    Thread.sleep(30000);
}
```